# Flutter | Extract item from object model

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model that returns data as shown below in a List:

```
[ GoodsModel(id: 483, productCategory: sport, productType: t-shirt, productDisplayName: Shirt, product_key: sport_goods, productRecommendation: null, sport_goods: {id: 12, name: t-shirt colored, color: blue}) ]
```

The value of the field **product_key** (sport_goods) matches with a map **sport_goods**
My question is, please, how can I extract only that piece of map 'sport_goods' based on the product_key?

```
var myMap = goodsList.map((e) {
        if (e. product_key == 'sport_goods') {
          return ???;
        }
      });
```

I am not sure how the **return** should look like. Any help please?

EDIT: I am starting to work on it. My ultimate goal is to have a list of widgets that will be created from the items returned from the piece of map. Like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GoodsList extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoodsList({super.key});

  @override
  State<GoodsList> createState() => _GoodsListState();
}

class _GoodsListState extends State<GoodsList> {
  // Data sample
  var data = {
    "id": 483,
    "productCategory": "sport",
    "productType": "t-shirt",
    "productDisplayName": "Shirt",
    "product_key": "sport_goods", // (2) based on this value
    "productRecommendation": null,
  // (1) I need to get this data
    "sport_goods": {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "t-shirt colored",
      "color": "blue",
    }
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // (3) how to get the piece of map in here???
      if (data[i]!['product_key'] == 'sport_goods') {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(data[i]!['sport_goods']!['id']),
            Text(data[i]!['sport_goods']!['name']),
            Text(data[i]!['sport_goods']!['color']),
          ],
        ) // This is the problem I believe
      }
    }

    return const Text('No data');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share all of your code that you have so far? Working code, up to the point where you need help

Comment: your code has several problems: 1) you create a stateful widget without ever making changes to the state, data could be static final or even static const. 2) you have a for loop for an iterator variable i, and you try to access `data` with `data[i]`, but `data` is most likely a map, so you can just access the key immediately (although it might be `null`), f.e.: `data['sport_goods']!['id']`. 3) although functional correct, its a bit odd, that you use a for loop here, since you effectively want to access a specific map entry and build something for that entry.

Comment: It looks like `data` is a map, but you are trying to index into it with an integer with `data[i]`, where `i` is an integer that comes from your `for`-loop. I think you can just get rid of the for loop and use ```if (data['product_key'] == 'sport_goods') {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(data['sport_goods']!['id']),
            Text(data['sport_goods']!['name']),
            Text(data['sport_goods']!['color']),
          ],
        )
      }```

Comment: all in all, you might wanna read about [JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/json), since JSON data also often is decoded as maps and then parsed into more "readable" dart objects to build widgets with that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this?

https://dartpad.dev/?id=9c0421e4a18b873fd5ec5e404ee57289

I'll paste the code here below so you can see - but the dartpad link should show you the output too.

```dart
class _GoodsListState extends State<GoodsList> {
  // Data sample
  var data = {
    "id": 483,
    "productCategory": "sport",
    "productType": "t-shirt",
    "productDisplayName": "Shirt",
    "product_key": "sport_goods",
    "productRecommendation": null,
    "sport_goods": {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "t-shirt colored",
      "color": "blue",
    }
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children:
        ((data['product_key'] ?? "") == "sport_goods") ?
          switch (data["sport_goods"]){
            {"id":int id, "name": String name, "color": String color} => [Text(id.toString()), Text(name), Text(color)],
             _ => [const Text('No Data')]
          }
          :[const Text('No Data')]
  }
}
```

The first part of the `children` is a check to see if the `product_key` == `sport_goods`, and if so, uses pattern matching to create the children list of `Text` widgets.

If the pattern matching fails, or if the `product_key` != `sport_goods`, in both cases we return a list of a single `Text` with "No Data" as the content.

Hopefully this helps you

Comment: @ loganrussell48 that solved my issue! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myMap = {};
  for (var goods in goodsList) {
    if (goods.productKey == 'sport_goods') {
      myMap = goods.sport_goods;
    }
  }
```

You can use above code snippet to retrieve the map stored in `sport_goods` key.

Here, we are initializing `myMap` variable.
Then we are searching the `goodsList` where `productKey` is `sports_good`.
And finally storing it in `myMap`.